# Hashmap in JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to generate a JSON response with translations from Ruby on Rails. The preferred response should be the following:

```
{"localization":{"en" => {"title" => "Test"}, "nl" => {"title => "Test"}}}
```

I have a translations collection that contains all the translations from a model. I tried the following without success.

Ruby Hash:

```
{ localization: translations.map { |t| { t.locale => { title: t.title } }} }.to_json
```

This resulted in:

```
{"localization":[{"en":{"title":"Far far away"}},{"nl":{"title":"Ik ben makelaar"}}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
{ 
  localization: Hash[translations.map{|t| [t.locale, {title: t.title}]}] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `methods` option with as_json and create your custom output. Like

In your translation class

```
class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base

 def localization
  {locale => {"title" => title}}
 end
end
```

Execute via

```
Traslation.all.collect do |translation|

translation.as_json(only: [],methods: :localization)

end
```